# Song identification from an old anime

Tags: music, saint-seiya

I've been trying with no luck to identify this [**song**](http://picosong.com/4dwt/). It is from an old anime but besides that no clue. Anyone who might know something?

Comment: Can you provide the source who led you to this song?
Do you know the anime name?

Comment: It is from Saint Seiya. I don't know the name of the track though.

Answer (score 4):

It is *[Sad Brothers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O-8kTRHiyoM&app=desktop)* from Saint Seiya OST I, played from the middle. Thanks to @hkBattousai for the clue.